# Event Monitoring: Is it possible to export all data of a certain EventType over a period of time into just one Event Log file?

Tags: event, eventlogfile, monitoring

If one wishes to see the logs for a particular Event Type over a period of time, the user has to manually go into each Event Log file one by one. Since one Event Log file is generated per day, this can be quite tedious. For example, if you wanted to see how many users looked at a particular Visualforce page over a 30 day period, you would have to look at 30 Event Log files.

Is there a way in which to generate a ***single*** Event Log file for the Event Types which you wish to analyse? For example, a better way would be if one could say 'for this 30 day period, show me all the logs where the EventType = 'VisualforceRequest'. That would save a lot of time.

Comment: we export all of our logs into SumoLogic using's Sumo's SFDC Connector App (free)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe this is possible with the current Spring '17 functionality. The SOQL queries on EventLogFile have no way to combine the contents of the corresponding LogFile fields.

It wouldn't be too difficult to have a developer merge multiple CSV files from a query into a single combined one.

Otherwise you could try raising something on the idea exchange.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. "It wouldn't be too difficult to have a developer merge multiple CSV files from a query into a single combined one." - this would be done via powershell, I assume?

Comment: Powershell is one option. I've got some basic .NET code that queries and pulls down the event log files. Combining two CSV files should just be a matter of removing one header and concatenating what is left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app:https://app.salesforce-compare.com/

Create a connection, then tick the "load events" checkbox, wait a while
and go to "Monitor" to view the different event types in the selected org

If you are not satisified with my visual representation of the data you can export the data for the selected time range

All the event types are exportable but only some have visual representations

Note that only "Insecure External Assets", "Login", and "Logout" are available at no additional cost

I am the developer of the app

Comment: Please make your affiliation with that app more obvious than the word "my" in third paragraph of your answer. (See *[Expected Behavior > Avoid overt self-promotion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)* and *[How to not be a spammer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)*.) I, for one, though, would never enter my credentials into a randomly linked app that has no introduction, privacy policy, terms of service, etc.

Comment: Roger that. I will clarify and add those.

Comment: You replied to my comment yesterday shortly after I posted it, yet you have not yet edited your answer to clarify your affiliation with the linked app.

Comment: I am the developer of the app, that is my affiliation to the app. I am in the process of creating a web site where I will add all the relevant information about the app

Comment: For more info on the app, see https://www.salesforce-compare.com